# Magento - log admin user activity

Tags: magento

i have a usergroup called: productUpdater that have rights to update products and stuff. Is there any easy way to log these users? 
Have a employee that i think are doing much less work than he is telling me...

Is there any logging default in magento that i dont know about or maybe there is a free/cheap plugin?

Magento ver. 1.8.1.0

Comment: FYI, not free but Magento Enterprise includes admin action logging capability by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its no problem to pay some money, but $15,550 is way to much.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension which you can use to see the list of actions performed by each admin users. This is paid one. Please see the below link

https://amasty.com/admin-actions-log.html